# Index 49 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 49 python numpy

Tags: python, debugging

Sooooo I'm completely lost.
I've created an array using 
length = zeros(num_particles, dtype=object)
num_particles = 51
when printing len(length) I get 52 returned.

I'm getting the error linked:
Index 49 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 49

This is in a for loop set

```
for leng in range(num_particles):
        x_squared = (r[particle,0] - x[leng])**2
        y_squared = (r[particle,1] - y[leng])**2
        distance = sqrt(x_squared + y_squared)
        lengths[leng]=distance
```

Whole code below:

```
def cdf(r, S, dr, dim):
from numpy import zeros, sqrt, where, pi, mean, arange, histogram, absolute, sort, delete, nonzero, amin, empty
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning) 
num_particles  = len(r)
rMax           = S/2.0;
edges          = arange(0., rMax + dr, dr)
num_increments = len(edges) - 1
radii          = zeros(num_increments + 1)
numberDensity  = len(r) / S**dim

void_particles = zeros(3, dtype=object, order='C')

x = zeros(num_particles)

y = zeros(num_particles)

n=num_particles

lengths = zeros(n + 1, dtype=object)

print(lengths)

print (num_particles)

print(len(lengths))

for pos in range(num_particles):
    x[pos]=r[pos,0]
    y[pos]=r[pos,1]

for particle in range(num_particles):

    for leng in range(num_particles):
        x_squared = (r[particle,0] - x[leng])**2
        y_squared = (r[particle,1] - y[leng])**2
        distance = sqrt(x_squared + y_squared)
        lengths[leng]=distance

    lengths = lengths[ lengths != np.min(lengths)]
    void_particles[0] = r[particle]
    void_particles[1] = r[where(lengths == amin(lengths))]
    lengths = lengths[ lengths != np.min(lengths)]
    void_particles[2] = r[where(lengths == amin(lengths))]

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-74dbdb61732e> in <module>
----> 1 a=cdf(n_data, box_length, res_dr, 2)
2 print(a)

<ipython-input-33-411d9850684e> in cdf(r, S, dr, dim)
 36             y_squared = (r[particle,1] - y[leng])**2
 37             distance = sqrt(x_squared + y_squared)
---> 38             lengths[leng]=distance
 39 
 40         lengths = lengths[ lengths != np.min(lengths)]

IndexError: index 49 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 49
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzrFh.png

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Python indexes are zero-based.  The first element is `[0]`, therefore index `[49]` is actually the fiftieth element.

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: what is `r`? my guess is that the invalid access is in the read from r, rather than the read from x or y, but it's hard to tell without knowing what it is.

Comment: r is an array with x and y coordinates

Answer (score 1):

The following expression shortens the array:

```
lengths = lengths[ lengths != np.min(lengths)]
```

and so the subsequent iterations — that assume that it still has `num_particles` elements — fail due to attempted out-of-bounds access.

Comment: So in that part I'm trying to find the shortest lengths from a given particle. What other way can I take the three shortest lengths indexes without removing them?

Answer (score 0):

You're not re-initializing `lengths` in each run of the outer loop.
Then inside the loop, when you do:
`lengths = lengths[ lengths != np.min(lengths)]`
you're shortening the `lengths` array to smaller than its original size. Then the next time you go through the loop, it's not as big as you expected and get the out of bounds.

Comment: So in that part I'm trying to find the shortest lengths from a given particle. What other way can I take the three shortest lengths indexes without removing them?

Comment: @DaddyDevito `sorted(lengths)[:3]`